# What type of SVM should I use for datasets of less and more than 10000 samples?

Tags: svm, python, scikit-learn, libsvm

I have 6 datatasets:

Dataset1: 2548 samples

Dataset2: 5167 samples

Dataset3: 2490 samples

Dataset4: 9113 samples

Dataset5: 7332 samples

Dataset6: 26650 samples

Dataset6 is the combination of the other 5. 
I am using sklearn. What SVM should I use?

a) svm.SVC : based on libsvm
   kernels:rbf (x defect), linear, poly, sigmoid, precomputed
   Cannot scale to dataset with more than 10000 samples

b) svm.LinearSVC : similar to svm.SVC + linear kernel. But implemented in « liblinear ». 
   Scales better to a large number of samples.

I think that I can only use b). Because it scales to large datasets even though that means that I can only try 1 type of kernel.

Comment: Why not try both and see what works better?

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. I just hoped that there could be a "rational" explanation. Because I have 6 datasets and the computing time is long.

Comment: It all just comes down to computational complexity vs. performance. If you can fit them, try both and see what's better. If a nonlinear kernel takes too long to be useful, then there's your answer as to which to use. Linear SVM fits fast but if you want something nonlinear, SVM is really slow with nonlinear kernels so maybe you should try trees or something else (personally with the data that I work on, SVM is never competitive in terms of time and performance with RFs and GBTs).

Comment: FYI the "size" of the dataset should include not just # samples, but also # features (i.e. "width" of the [data matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_matrix_(multivariate_statistics))).

Comment: @GeoMatt22 I think OP only mentioned / emphasized on # of samples is because SVM kernel matrix is directly related to # of rows, and # of columns may not that important.

Comment: @hxd1011 OK. I have not used SVM, but for modern applications, is $\mathrm{O}[10^4]$ really considered "big"? (Wikpedia seems to suggest reasonable SVM implementations would use [specialized approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization), vs. a generic QP solver?)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 if the data is 1e4, then the matrix is 1e4 by 1e4, may be too tough for QP solver? My own experience is it seems takes very long time for SVM on the sale of 1e5 rows of data.

Comment: @hxd1011 I guess that makes sense. I am used to large sparse matrices (as in PDEs), and there "matrix free" approaches are common. It's [web page](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) says "LIBLINEAR is a linear classifier for data with millions of instances and features." Has there been work done on "matrix free" solvers for kernel-ML methods? (Or the [matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) are just not amenable to this?)